# How to determine if an html div element is completed loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

On clicking a load button in a jsp (1.jsp), another jsp(2.jsp) is loaded in a div element of the original jsp(1.jsp).
This loaded div jsp has some large datatable and html elements that take time to configure (a few seconds.) During this time it would be useful to show the user a loading dialog or wait screen as the jsp is not fully ready. 
I tried using jquery modal as well as jquery show/hide as follows

```
   $("#loadpage").show();       
   $("#divElement").load("2.jsp");               
   $("#loadpage").hide();
```

but the probelm is that the hide() is called before the 2.jsp is fully loaded.
How to keep a loading gif untill the 2.jsp is fully loaded????

Comment: `load()` has a callback function you can use, but it's also deprecated (the entire load() function used this way is, you should do .`on('load', function() {..}` instead, and even that is'nt really a very good idea IMO)!

Comment: @adeneo You can't use `load` on a div element to check when it's loaded - that's the deprecated one, and it can only be used on images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object. You can use `load` to load contents with AJAX into it, and use its callback, and that version is not deprecated.

Comment: @Ian - you are indeed right, just me reading the question way to fast?

Comment: @adeneo Who knows! Haha the dual-meaning of `load` is annoying to me. But then again, I also never liked the shortcut methods for `bind("event")` - which is why there is confusion. Anyways, I just wanted to explain...the reason it's deprecated seems to be just for the lack of or inconsistency in support of a `load` event. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the call back function of the load function

```
 $("#divElement").load("2.jsp", function () {
     $("#loadpage").hide();
 });
```

> Callback Function
>   If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.

For more information you can see the [JQuery Documentation of load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

**EDIT** (after comment):
 If you want to check the error  you can implement the function the following way :

```
function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        // Do something on error
    } else {
        $("#loadpage").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to check for success/error in the callback (depends on if the OP cares or not), otherwise this looks good :)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a function in load. it will be get called once download of 2.jsp complete.

```
  $("#divElement").load("2.jsp", function(){

         // content is loaded
  });
```